# Pass function pointer to template

Tags: c++

I did have a situation very much akin to this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class B>
class A
{
public:
    A<B>(const B& b) : m_b(b) {}
    void foo()
    {
        m_b(*this);
    }
private:
    B m_b;
};

class B
{
public:
    template<class C>
    void operator()(const C& c)
    {
        std::cout << "Bar!\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    B b;        
    A<B> a(b);
    a.foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Then I decided to use a function pointer instead of the function object b, i.e. I wanted to do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class B>
class A
{
public:
    A<B>(const B& b) : m_b(b) {}
    void foo()
    {
        m_b(*this);
    }
private:
    B m_b;
};

template<class C>
void bar(const C& c)
{
std::cout << "Bar!\n";
}

int main()
{
    typedef void (*barPointer)(const A<barPointer>& a); // <--       
    A<barPointer> a(&bar);
    a.foo();

    return 0;
}
```

This obviously does not compile (notice the circularity at <--). My question is: how would one go about this?

Comment: The simplest solution is to go back to a function object; this can also have performance benefits, since it is much easier to inline. Do you have a particular reason for wanting a function pointer instead?

Comment: How are function objects easier to inline? A function is easy to inline iff its body is visible. That holds for a member function as well as for a free function.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: The member function is specified at compile time by the template argument, so can easily be inlined. The target of the function pointer is specified at run-time by the constructor argument; the compiler may not be able to tell what it is, and may not inline it even if it can.

Comment: @MikeSeymour if the functor's member operator()() is defined in a different CU then how is it easier to inline than a function defined in a different CU?

Comment: @wilhelmtell: Who said anything about translation units? The difference is that the member function, `T::operator()`, is specified at compile time, and the value of the function pointer, `&bar<A>`, is specified at run time. Hence one is known to the compiler and can easily be inlined; the other might not be.

Comment: isn't std::function just what you need ?

Comment: @JoelFalcou : the problem with `std::function` is with the current definition of `basePointer`, it too would end up being infinitely recursive.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key question to ask is what is your `barPointer` type? It is a pointer-to-a-function, but as you've attempted to define it, you've created an infinitely recursive definition.  To end the recursion, you have to consider what the "root" or "base-case" of this pointer type is. Since you know the type for the instance of `A` you will be passing to your function, then you really are looking for a "placeholder" type that will allow the template to be instantiated without the circularity.  This could be a very "generic" function-pointer type like `void(*)(void*)`, or it could be something more specific, but in either case, I believe it needs to be a function pointer type that does not include the definition of `A`, but can be passed an `A<>` instance as its argument.  The most generic form would be a `void(*)(void*)`, but you can always define some type of polymorphic base-class as well for greater type safety.

Here, for instance, would be an example of the most generic case:

```
typedef void (*generic_t)(void*);

template<typename T>
struct A
{
        A(const T& t): func_ptr(t) {}
        void foo() { func_ptr(this); }
        T func_ptr;
};

void func(void* arg)
{
        const A<generic_t>* a = reinterpret_cast<const A<generic_t>*>(arg);
}

int main()
{
        A<generic_t> a(&func);
        a.foo();
        return 0;
}
```

Although this looks dangerous, it's not really if you consider the fact that in your `basePointer` example you already knew the type of object you were going to pass to your `basePointer` function pointer.  If you want more type-safety to prevent inadvertent mistakes, you could always create some type of abstract base class that `A` inherits from.  I say "abstract Base class" because that would allow you to use the pointer passed to the function without an explicit cast to it's derived type. Then your "generic placeholder" function-ptr type could be something like `void(*)(const Base&)` rather than the non-type-safe `void(*)(void*)`.